# How much information can be stored in a system with synthetic dimensions?

Tags: condensed-matter, entropy, spacetime-dimensions, information, floquet-theory

Okay this is a completely serious question and keep in mind I have a PhD in theoretical condensed matter physics, in which I have somewhat of a specialization in Floquet physics. So as the title says, 'How much information can be stored in a system with synthetic dimensions?' So the principle of the Bekenstein bound says that there is only so much entropy or information that you can store within a three dimensional space or four dimensional space, including time. So let's say that we already apply the Bekenstein bound to four dimensional space. But what if you include synthetic dimensions? If we apply the equivalent of the Bekenstein bound to a six dimensional space, will the information density end up working out to be the same as if you apply the Bekenstein bound to a four dimensional space or will you be able to store more information within this six dimensional space? Basically, this is a question of whether you can create a bigger on the inside space, like in Doctor Who.

I feel like this question is not an unscientific question because it is legitimately a question as opposed to imposing various beliefs on other people.

Here are a couple good sources for explaining sythetic dimensions:https://www.azoquantum.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=303 , https://opg.optica.org/optica/fulltext.cfm?uri=optica-5-11-1396&id=400075

Comment: What does your degree has to do with the question?

Comment: Cross posted from [QC SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27448/how-much-information-can-be-stored-in-a-system-with-synthetic-dimensions)

Comment: @JasonFunderberker It just shows that I am unable to answer the question even though I have a good amount of experience in the relevant field. I can remove that if you want.

Comment: @ctimms137  Please do not remove the background you have. It helps people who answer the questions.